# Is there a way to apply custom CSS before printing a page in a browser?

Tags: html, css, pdf, web-scraping, printing

I occasionally save tutorials from a website as a PDF file for future reference.

My current manual workflow is:

1. Click the "show on one page" link to get a full single page view of the article.
2. Open the **DevTools** of the browser and select sections with advertisements and related links with help of the **inspect**-functionality and remove them.
3. Print the page as a PDF file.

I used the **Firefox** or **Chrome**-Browser for this, as they both have the required functionality and behave very similarly in that regard.

I noticed that the content I want to remove to get a "clean print" of the content is mostly the same: Let's say all adds are embedded with a div with the class **add-banner**.

Is there a way to automate these steps?
One idea is to load a custom CSS file that I would need to prepare specifically for a site. Simple rules like `.add-banner { display: none; }` would allow me to hide the sections that I don't want to print.

I also took a look at console based scrapers because I like the idea to call a command with the URL as a parameter. But the tools I've discovered are image based and I want a indexable PDF file where I can search for text and select parts.

What is the best option to achieve this?

Comment: If the owner of the content wanted you to be able to rebrand it, they would create an api or feed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension **User CSS** from the **chrome web store** (free) allows me to add custom css rules to whatever page is loaded. It is possible to import and export CSS rules and the extension allows to store the custom CSS on a per site base.

This is exactly what I was looking for, since it makes it easier and quicker for me to remove unwanted sections before printing.